When call a batch job from scheduler.rb got some errors like gemnot found
I am trying to download the database dump from RDS using a rake task, and it works perfectly when run individually.
However, when I try to run it as a scheduled batch, I encounter some errors. its in docker. I'll attach the error details below.
schedule.rb file
env :PATH, ENV['PATH']
env :GEM_PATH, ENV['GEM_PATH']
set :environment, "development"


every 1.minute do
  # Echo command to log the time when the cron job is triggered
  command "echo 'Cron job triggered at $(date)' >> log/cron_debug.log"
  
  # Run the rake task with `bundle exec` and specify logs for output
  rake "db:dump", output: { 
    error: 'log/failure_cron.log', 
    standard: 'log/success_cron.log' 
  },  task: 'bundle exec rake'
end

failure_cron.log
bundler: failed to load command: rake (/usr/local/bin/rake)
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.2.0/bundler/definition.rb:599:in `materialize': Could not find rails-7.1.3, rails-i18n-7.0.8, rails-observers-0.1.5, rack-cors-2.0.1, puma-6.4.2, autoprefixer-rails-10.4.16.0, mysql2-0.5.6, redis-5.1.0, tzinfo-data-1.2024.1, nokogiri-1.16.2-x86_64-linux, activerecord-session_store-2.1.0, aws-sdk-3.2.0, aws-sdk-rails-3.10.0, aws-sdk-s3-1.143.0, aws-sdk-rds-1.252.0, net-ssh-7.3.0, net-scp-4.0.0, sidekiq-7.2.1, sidekiq-status-3.0.3, sidekiq-scheduler-5.0.3, sinatra-4.0.0, browser-5.3.1, recaptcha-5.16.0, invisible_captcha-2.2.0, 
Want to download the db dumb through the batch.


Just to clarify you did follow the steps as provided by the whenever gem correct. i.e. bundle exec wheneverize . from the root of your application or at least put the schedule.rb file in the config directory. Also I am unaware of any need for the first 3 lines in your schedule.rb file, bundel exec will execute the command in the context of the bundle there is no need to set PATH or GEM path or honestly even environment (if it is already set in the actual environment)
